# Use i3 on a 4k monitor

Tags: display-resolution, i3-wm, 4k-monitor

I've decided to change my windows manager to have a tiling windows manager. Since I heard a lot of good from i3, I've chosen to go for it. Problem is, I have a 4k monitor and as I switched to i3, it feels like everything is really tiny. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 btw.

So I switch the resolution to 1920x1080 with xrandr, but I was wondering if there was any way to make i3 adapt itself to the 4k resolution?

I'm open to eventual other window manager suggestions, since I'm not yet very used to i3.

Comment: Try this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267885/how-do-i-scale-i3-window-manager-for-my-hidpi-display

Comment: Thanks! modifying the Xresources file did the trick for me! :)

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz , could you write an answer for that solution.